# using one query to set range for second query

Tags: azure-sql-database

Good Morning

I have the following problem.  Effective I am trying to use the resulting client list from the first query to pass into the second query to extract the list of transactions I need to extract.

I am new to sql so not even sure if it is possible.  Can anyone advise a solution please

```
--create list of client_accs 

select client_id, client_acc
from client_crm
where client_id = 'LOG0000240'

--select transaction data for list of client generated in first query

Select 
client_id,
test_cash_trans.client_acc,
sub_trans_type,
settle_date,
dbt_crt,
test_cash_trans.currency,
cash_amount,
test_cash_trans.last_update
From test_cash_trans

inner join client_crm
on test_cash_trans.client_acc = client_crm.client_acc

where test_cash_trans.client_acc in --- result of first query

group by client_id,test_cash_trans.client_acc, sub_trans_type, settle_date, dbt_crt, test_cash_trans.currency, cash_amount,test_cash_trans.last_update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `IN`:

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN   
    ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]  
    )
```

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName  
FROM Person.Person AS p  
    JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp  
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID IN  
   (SELECT BusinessEntityID  
   FROM Sales.SalesPerson  
   WHERE SalesQuota > 250000);
```

More information: [IN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql)